# CKEditor 5 change event not always firing

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using CKeditor v11.1.1 with CountableJS for wordcounting.

Currently, I attach countable like this:

`editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', ( evt, data ) => { //call countableJS wordcount });`

This works fine for normal typing and backspaces, but fails when I do `CTRL+A -> Delete` or `CTRL+V` paste some text. The event doesn't fire and so the wordcount doesn't update until I start typing again.

The docs specifically say "[change:data] is fired for changes which affect the editor data" but that doesn't seem to always be the case. I have also tried listening to just `change` but that behaved similarly.

Am I misunderstanding something here? Is there another event I can listen to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just checked it and it works for me just fine when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. You can test it on https://jsfiddle.net/auxe23b7/1/:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( editor );

        editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', ( evt, data ) => {
            console.log( data );
        } );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

In fact, if this event would not be fired, the editor would not work. This event begins the conversion of the changes in the model to the view. If some changes (deleting the content, pasting some content) are not converted, they would not appear in the view.

So, either you have a bug in your code or... or I don't know :)

Comment: It does appear that the event is firing correctly. This fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/auxe23b7/5/ logs the wordcount above the editor and clearly shows my error where the wordcount does not get updated when you CTRL+A Delete. I know @Reinmar you're not responsible for CountableJS, so I'm wondering if you can see any issue from the CKEditor side

Comment: In fact, check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/auxe23b7/7/ which outputs `$(editor.ui.view.editable.element).html()` and shows what is being fed into CountableJS. When the `change:data` event fires, the html in that element is not yet updated and so the wordcount is off. Is there a different way I can get the editable element?

Comment: I can feed `editor.getData()` to Countable and it will work correctly, so I guess that is a solution for now. But I'm hoping you can explain why the previous method failed

Comment: No idea. But you shouldn't rely on the HTML of the editing area. It can be very different from what `getData()` produces.

Comment: PS. Don't forget about accepting/upvoting answers ;)

Comment: i do not. never forget